# Software testing tools for testing web application

Tags: testing

may I ask if there is any recommended tools for testing web application written in PHP, JavaScript, etc?

Currently, I am doing a research to find out software testing tools for testing web application efficiently. May I ask if there is any recommended tools?

Or is there any recommendation on what direction I may follow in doing a research like this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of web application testing tools out there. Here are several lists of them:

http://freshmeat.net/articles/open-source-java-and-web-testing-tools

http://java-source.net/open-source/web-testing-tools

http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html

Specifically, [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a very popular tool.

Answer (score 2):

It's dependent which tests do you want to have. For unit tests I used PHPUnit, tehre is maybe now better one.

For web tests there is Selenium and [WebTest](http://webtest.canoo.com/) I'm using. Selenium is really easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Tools for web application testing

- Selenium Web driver mostly used Testing for Web Application.
  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
- Jasmine -Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code.
  http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html
- Waitr - for Web Application Testing in Ruby
- There many tools for Automation
  http://www.opensourcetesting.org/functional.php
  http://devzone.zend.com/1014/acceptance-testing-of-web-applications-with-php/

Try with selenium Web driver